# Docker Compose Error for accessing MariaDB

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb

Although, I was able to successfully run my docker-compose.yml file. I am unable to access to MariaDB through Streamlit python app. This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services: 
    app: 
        restart: always 
        build: ./app 
        ports: 
            - "8501:8501"
        command: streamlit run Main.py 

    mariadb: 
        image: mariadb:10.5.17 
        ports: 
            - "xxx.xx.xx.xx:3307:3307"
        volumes: 
        - db_data:/var/lib/mysql 
        - db_conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d 
        environment: 
            MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
            MARIADB_DATABASE: testtest 
            MARIADB_USER: testing
            MARIADB_PASSWORD: passtest
        networks: 
            - streamlit_network  

    nginx: 
        restart: always 
        build: ./nginx 
        ports: 
            - "80:80"
        depends_on: 
            - app 
            - mariadb 

volumes: 
    db_data: 
    db_conf: 

networks: 
    streamlit_network: 
        external: true
```

And my python file reading data from MariaDB:

```
 conn = pymysql.connect(
            host=os.environ.get("host"),
            user=os.environ.get("user"),
            password=os.environ.get("password"),
            database=os.environ.get("database"),
            cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
    )
```

And my .env file is in this format:

```
# Environment variables defined inside a .env file 
host="mariadb"
user="xxx"
password="xxx"
database="xxx"
port="xxx"
```

This is the error message:

```
**OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address)")**
```

I am not sure how I can connect to MariaDB. MariaDB actually has an IP address that I need to connect to. Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Comment: a) I thought the `host=` was the `container_name`. b) `MARIADB_ROOT_HOST` needs to be the IP of the `app`, or omitted (probably easier). c) `/etc/mysql/conf.d` should be the mount point for `db_conf`. d) There's also a `healthcheck.sh --connect` script that can be used in to determine availability for compose. A) What is the exact error in the app logs? Edit the question with details.

Comment: @danblack I edited the description with the error message and added some more details. I corrected those things you pointed out did not seem to fix it. Akso, I am not sure about the healthcheck.sh --connect script do you have an example for that? Thanks

Comment: The error msg says that it is trying to connect to `localhost`, not your MySQL container `maria_db`.

Answer (score 0):

Where is this .env file kept?

Also, you have defined and 'user' and 'username' for the user.

Same with mariadb host defined with two variables: mariadb and maria_db.
It seems like it is not able to resolve and trying to connect to localhost.

Comment: The .env file is kept on the same level as the docker-compose file. Username is just a dummy name I used here to hide the actual value. And I just had a typo here for mariadb. I am not exactly sure why is it trying to connect to localhost instead of this configuration.

Comment: Why do you have app in 'frontend' network and db in 'backend' network? Shoudn't they be in same network for connection to work?  see https://runnable.com/docker/docker-compose-networking

Comment: Alright, I modified the docker-compose and created a network called `streamlit_network`. But now, I can't get docker-compose up --build -d to work. I have a warning: Host is already in use by another container. And This error: ERROR: for mariadb  Cannot start service mariadb: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint  Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 xxx.xx.xx.xxx:3307 bind: cannot assign requested address
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project. I did change the port from 3306 to 3307 as there was already mysql listening there.

Comment: Can you try recreating the cluster after removing conflicting setup? seems like few containers are already running with similar parameters as mentioned in new compose file.

Comment: I was able to fix that error but when I run `docker run python Main.py` it is hanging there. I am not seeing anything being output. And when I ping the site IP it is not reachable as well. Are there any additional steps required for setting up MariaDB credentials for access? I have this IP address where MariaDB is hosted and can't seem to be using it anywhere.

Comment: What are you trying to do with  'docker run python Main.py'. This is not correct syntax. You are already running container using docker-compose. And, docker run command isn't supposed to be executed like this.